# How to make my django website live to the world after setting up my application with Digital Ocean Droplet?

Tags: django, git, nginx, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy my Django website using Digital Ocean Droplet. I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps) documentation to setup my application with Digital Ocean droplet using Nginx and Gunicorn. After this the website is properly running on my system if I visit to my domain name in the bowser. But now I am confused that how should make my website available over the internet to the world. Below is the nginx settings I have used as per the documentation I followed:

```
server {
    server_name 46.101.156.167;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/myapp/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

Above given server_name is the IP of my droplet which is redirected to the domain name of my website.

It would be great if any one can guide me with step by step documentation to make my website live. I believe the Digital Ocean should take my website from the repo in git or bitbucket so that in case of further changes I just need to push my code to the repo and than my droplet can use the updated code. But I am ber much confused about how to do it.

Comment: You just said the website works of you visit the domain name in your browser. So what's the problem?

Comment: It is working only on my local system. I checked the website from another system but it was not updated.
What I was thinking is I started the nginx server from my system's terminal and that may be the reason that the website is running only on my system. Could you please guide me a way how to make it run using Digital Ocean console so that the website gets up for everyone.

Comment: I tried to generate ssh key so that i can login to user@publicdomainorip from the console to run the nginx server. I was able to generate the ssh key successfully also added the same in control panel of Digital Ocean but when I tried to login from `ssh user@publicdomainorip` (using my user name and ip address of Digital Ocean) it is not getting connected and showing 'Connection Time Out'. Also, now when I restarted the nginx on my system and tried to visit the domain it is showing 'Bad Request (400)'. I am totally confused now where to go and how to proceed. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the note that i have written here:

https://www.facebook.com/notes/django-python-web-framework/django-deployment-in-digitalocean-nginx-and-gunicorn/1012584968792749